# food-menu problem in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

I am trying to create a food menu for a boarding school. The idea is to let the students view what they have on menu for the whole day. That is, breakfast, lunch and dinner. This menu would be prepopulated weekly by a user.

My problem are as follows:
 1) How do i use view module to just display items for one day?
 2) Do i need like a date field, and calender module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Date module](http://www.drupal.org/project/date).

- Add a date field to your 'boardingschoolmenu' content type.
- Then in views you would add the fields you want visible (breakfast, lunch, dinner, etc)
- Add a filter on content type 'boardingschoolmenu'
- Add an argument for the date field. In the settings of the argument, under "Action to take if argument is not present", select: `Provide default argument` followed by: `Current date` (or can use php code if you want another date).